# No me deja conectarme a mi base de datos en my xampp en local desde el emulador

Tags: java, mysql, android, connection

Mi clase de conexión es la siguiente:

```
public Connection getRemoteConnection() {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        String dbName = "signal";
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "";
        String hostname = "192.168.0.22";
        String port = "3306";
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/" + dbName + "?user=" + userName + "&password=" + password;

        System.out.println("Getting remote connection with connection string.");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
        System.out.println("Remote connection successful.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace();} catch (java.sql.SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }

    return con;
}
```

Este es el error que me aparece: (No me deja conectarme a mi base de datos a pesar de poder acceder al localhost con la ip de mi ordenador) (el usuario y contraseña son por defecto de xampp "root" y "")

```
W/System.err: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1006)
W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823)
W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453)
W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:236)
```

Y esta son las dependencias que tengo:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.23'
    implementation  'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Simplemente ahora quiero la conexión pero es sin éxito. Soy capaz de abrir el localhost desde mi dispositivo emulado .[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO!

Comment: Ese mensaje de error no lo dice todo, sugiero que agregues la traza completa a tu pregunta a ver si allí se puede ver la causa del problema.

Comment: Ya está editado, espero que esté mejor, gracias.

Comment: prueba cambiando tu puerto a 80  y tu hostname cambialo por localhost o 127.0.0.0, además podrías agregar el código donde mandas llamar getRemoteConnection() porfavor.